# Cannot perform mapquest.com searchQuery

Tags: mapquest

I cannot perform search query.
https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/searchahead-sdk/android/v1.3/
Tells me that this is correct but it wont work. It throws me an error

```
private void searchQuery(String queryString){
    SearchAheadService mSearchAheadServiceV3;
    mSearchAheadServiceV3 = new SearchAheadService(mContext, "uZW4cZzRkNqXaK9oHOrgJVEb6rk3oVM0");
    List searchCollections = Arrays.asList(SearchCollection.AIRPORT, SearchCollection.ADMINAREA,
            SearchCollection.ADDRESS);
    try {
        SearchAheadQuery query = new SearchAheadQuery.Builder(queryString, searchCollections).location(new LatLng((float)MapsActivity.mLastLocation.getLatitude(), (float)MapsActivity.mLastLocation.getLongitude())).build();
        mSearchAheadServiceV3.predictResultsFromQuery(query,
                new SearchAheadService.SearchAheadResponseCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull SearchAheadResponse searchAheadResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Search Ahead V3 Success - Response: " + searchAheadResponse);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Search Ahead V3 Failure", e);
                    }
                });
    } catch (IllegalQueryParameterException e) {
        L.e("Error performing search", e);
    }
}
```

But i got this error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: Method org.apache.http.HttpResponse com.mapquest.android.commoncore.network.volley.NetworkHelper$InitialRequestQueueSupplier$1.performRequest(com.android.volley.Request, java.util.Map) overrides final method in class Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/BaseHttpStack; (declaration of 'com.mapquest.android.commoncore.network.volley.NetworkHelper$InitialRequestQueueSupplier$1' appears in /data/app/com.example.locolusmap-S4zcpMbjISCjpC9YmZe9SQ==/base.apk:classes3.dex)
```

Comment: try adding volley dependency explicitly or try latest version of existing query dependency

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that the development team is aware of and we hope to have a fix for this soon. It will be part of the next version of the SDK. I don't have an ETA.